# Unable to link multiple items to an order in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an API for a resturant where each user has a cart and they can add multiple items in it. Once the order is placed all items are supposed to be replicated and store to OrderItem model and a order is also created to hold information like total price, list of order items etc.

What I am trying to here is to link all the order items to order id so that I can see a nested data with all associated order items.

Everything is fine till adding items to cart.

here is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,db_index=True)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
class MenuItem(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    featured = models.BooleanField(db_index=True,null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)

    class Meta:

        unique_together = ['menuitem','user']

class OrderList(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)

class Test(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery_crew = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='delivery_crew', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True,auto_now_add=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=1)


    class Meta:

        unique_together = ['menuitem','order']
```

here is my views.py

```
class OrderView(views.APIView):

    def post(self,request):

        endpoint = request.POST.get('endpoint', False)
        if endpoint == 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart/menu-items':

            total = 0
            user = self.request.user
            cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
            for item in cart_items:
                total += item.price
            
            if Order.objects.filter(user=user):
                o = Order.objects.get(user=user)
                o.total = total
                o.save()
            else:
                Order.objects.create(user=user,total=total)

            order = Order.objects.filter(user=user).first()

            for item in cart_items:

                menuitem = item.menuitem
                price_per_unit = float(item.unit_price)
                price = float(item.price)
                quantity = item.quantity
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,menuitem=menuitem,unit_price=price_per_unit,price=price,quantity=quantity)

            cart_items.delete()
   
            return Response({'message':'order placed successfully'})
        
        return Response({'message':'invalid endpoint'})
        
    def get(self, request):


        user = self.request.user

        queryset = Order.objects.filter(user=user)

        serialized_item = OrderSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serialized_item.data)
```

here is my serializer.py

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = OrderItem
        fields = '__all__'
    
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
        items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

        class Meta:

            model = Order
            fields = '__all__'
```

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('cart', views.CartView.as_view()),
    path('orders',views.OrderView.as_view()),
    path('orders/<int:id>',views.single_order_item),
```

I am not getting any nested data

```
[
    {
        "delivery_crew": null,
        "total": "16500.0",
        "status": false,
        "date": "2023-07-19"
    }
]
```

What I am expecting is something like:

```
{
  "user": A,
  "delivery_crew": "B",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Item 5"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Item 6"
    }
  ],
  "total" : $123
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Everything is fine till adding items to cart."? What happens when you add an item to cart? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I meant that I was able to add items to the cart and able to see the expected JSON. Before I didn't care about nested data but now I want to link each item added by user on cart with the order. Hope that helps

Comment: Please edit your question to show the expected JSON and the actual JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are defining an `items` attribute, you are not actually serializing it.

Basically, you need to retrieve the order items associated with the order
and serialize them in the OrderSerializer.

You may want to try something like this:

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        def get_items(self, order):
            return [
                OrderItemSerializer(item).data
                for item in order.orderitem_set.all()
            ]

        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = ['user', 'delivery_crew', 'total', 'status', 'date', 'items']
```